# Changing the colour of the font for var when append

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have temporary usernames set in varible so when some one in the chat writes something there username also shows up. how could i change the font colour of that var so its stands out when its appended to the message box?

this is the bit of code where the variable "name" is called.

```
App.room.speak( name + ":" + " " + event.target.value )
```

and here is the line in the jquery file where i assign it

```
name = $('#username').val();
```

ive tried a few different approaches but none seemed to work...

ideally id like to change the colour for every time its assigned.

Comment: please elaborate more detail of what you had done

Comment: wat does `speak` function accepts ? String or HTML ?

Comment: speak function accepts string, ill add some of the methods ive tried now. to be clear im a beginner at this

Comment: i tried:    App.room.speak( name.fontcolor("green"); + ":" + " " + event.target.value )

Comment: also tried this: $('#username').css({color: 'red'});